# filbreak adds extra vertical space

Tags: spacing, tasks

I'm writing a book with a long list of questions. Most questions come in parts.

At the bottom of a page it breaks after printing the number of the problem but before printing the parts, which is clearly not the result I want:

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

The simplest solution to this I thought would be to add a `\filbreak` after each problem. But that adds some extra space between items.

[image: Page 1 again]
[image: Page 2 again]

You can see in the previous version page 1 should fit 8 questions but only fits 7 now.

This is a real problem in the book I'm writing since the added space might be around `5mm` for each problem. How do I negate this problem?

Note that I cannot use `minipage` because it doesn't interact nicely with tasks.

```
    \documentclass[a5paper]{article}
    \usepackage{tasks}
    \begin{document}


    \section*{Here are some questions: }
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} \filbreak
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: would using `geometry` package or changing the `fontsize` be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\RenewEnviron {__tasks_env:} [3]
  {
    \if@inlabel
      \@beginparpenalty=10000 %new
      \noindent\par\nobreak\vskip-\parskip\vskip-\baselineskip\hrule\@height\z@
    \fi
    \dim_compare:nNnF { \l__tasks_before_list_skip } = { 0pt }
      { \vspace {\l__tasks_before_list_skip} }
    \list {}
      {
        \keys_set:nn {tasks/list} {#2}
        \dim_set:Nn \leftmargin  {0pt}
        \dim_set:Nn \rightmargin {0pt}
      }
    \item \scan_stop:
    \int_incr:N \l__tasks_depth_int
    \__tasks:VnnV \l__tasks_instance_tl {#3} {#1} \BODY
    \endlist
    \dim_compare:nNnF { \l__tasks_after_list_skip } = { 0pt }
      { \vspace {\l__tasks_after_list_skip} }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
    \begin{document}


    \section*{Here are some questions: }
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
        \item \begin{tasks}(2) \task $1$ \task $2$ \task $3$ \task $4$ \end{tasks} 
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```